# source code for text summarization by java

Tags: text, summarization

My project requires text summarizer. Is there any source code for this in **java**? Or if I must build it myself, is there any book on the subjects?

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely have to build a text summarizer yourself. Although there are some libraries, API's and software that do text summarizer you can maybe check them out to see if they are useful.

Here is a good website I found that describes 30+ text summarizer libraries, API's and software:
http://blog.mashape.com/post/58164039983/list-of-30-summarizer-apis-libraries-and-software

Hope this helps. Good Luck.